# How to prevent font awesome changing text in ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, fonts, font-awesome

It should be a simple one...

I have a button which i want to write text in and show a down arrow.
I use font awesome as the button font.

The arrow shows up fine, but the word "Category" shows up like this:

[image]

i've tried using back and forward slashes. it didn't help.

How can i prevent this?

Edit:

this is the code -

```
dropBtn.setTitle("category  \u{f0d7}", for: .normal)
```

Edit 2:

|I've managed to work around it by generating a custom font file only with the icons i need. 
i did it on fontello.com

Comment: Can your share your code?

Comment: Share your code where you are setting the title.

Comment: @Chris code added

Comment: Font Awesome seems to be interpreting “at” as “@“. Is this set up somewhere else in your code. I don’t think it’s standard behaviour. How are you using Font Awesome - which method or library is it? You could perhaps try doing the Unicode codes for the “a” and/or “t”. It’s hacky but might be a workaround!

Comment: tried using unicode for a and t. still getting @

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [FontAwesome.swift](https://github.com/thii/FontAwesome.swift).

It has a very simple syntax and is flexible and not prone to the sort of problem you have there.

Here is an example from the readme on GitHub (where they have other examples for buttons and toolbar items etc).

```
label.font = UIFont.fontAwesome(ofSize: 100, style: .brands)
label.text = String.fontAwesomeIcon(name: .github)
```

Comment: i've tried it as well.

        lbl.font = UIFont.fontAwesome(ofSize: 20, style: .solid)
        lbl.text = "category" + String.fontAwesomeIcon(name: .caretDown)

same result...